# Find matching pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains multiple strings pattern ('Q88 9WE','S9 D2P',WC2R 3LS etc..). How do I extract and split the rows that meet only the pattern

```
AN NAA,
ANN NAA,
AAN NAA,
AANN NAA,
ANA NAA,
AANA NAA.
```

Where A is a character in the range A-Z and N is a digit 1-9

I have tried using the logic below and it doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT case when len(a.Code) = 6 then
        case 
            when substring(a.code,1,1) LIKE '%[a-z]%' and  substring(a.code,2,1)  like substring(Code,PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', Code),1) and substring(a.code,3,1) = '' 
             and substring(a.code,4,1)  like PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', Code)
             then 1 
        end
      end as mapping , code
  FROM [dirtyTable] AS A
```

I'm trying to map each pattern to a number and I will later put in a  cte so I can do a select * from cte where mapping = 1. I'm having difficulty creating a case logic for multiple digit scenario.

Comment: What do you mean "extract and split"?  Sample data and desired results would clarify.

Comment: Looks like UK postcode validation, which I'm pretty sure has a bunch of existing solutions.

Comment: The "extract and split" as well as the `%` around your patterns hint, that this pattern is somewhere in the middle of a single- or multi-line text, your `substring` and `len(a.Code)` attempt hints in the other direction. Can you give us a bit more information about whether this code fills the column or needs to be found somewhere in the middle of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same idea as Gordon's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115872/11418272), but with a bit of code reuse to reduce chance of typos when entering a new pattern:

```
DECLARE @a CHAR(8) = '[a-zA-Z]' --can remove an a-z if not using a case-sensitive collation
    ,@n CHAR(5) = '[0-9]' --Can change to '[0-9.-]' as per OP's example if need to count these as numeric
    ,@s CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);
WITH [dirtyTable]
AS (
    SELECT code
    FROM (VALUES
             ('A1 1AA'  )
            ,('A11 1AA' )
            ,('AA1 1AA' )
            ,('AA11 1AA')
            ,('A1A 1AA' )
            ,('AA1A 1AA')
        ) t(code)
    )
SELECT code
FROM [dirtyTable]
WHERE code LIKE CONCAT(@a, @n, @s, @n, @a, @a          )
 OR string LIKE CONCAT(@a, @n, @n, @s, @n, @a ,@a      )
 OR string LIKE CONCAT(@a, @a, @n, @s, @n, @a ,@a      )
 OR string LIKE CONCAT(@a, @a, @n, @n, @s, @n ,@a , @a )
 OR string LIKE CONCAT(@a, @n, @a, @s, @n, @a ,@a      )
 OR string LIKE CONCAT(@a, @a, @n, @a, @s, @n ,@a , @a )
```

If you wanted to use your original approach, it wasn't working for a couple of reasons:

1. One of your substrings was searching for an empty string ('') rather than a space (' ')
2. Your code was inconsistent: the first number search used `PatIndex` nested inside `Substring` (achieves desired result), but in the 2nd usage (looking at the 4th character), you missed off the `Substring` function (searches for something different, breaking the query).

With those errors corrected:

```
SELECT case when len(a.Code) = 6 then
        case 
            when substring(a.code,1,1) LIKE '%[a-z]%' 
                and substring(a.code,2,1) like substring(Code,PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', Code),1)
                and substring(a.code,3,1) = ' '
                and substring(a.code,4,1) like substring(Code,PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', Code),1)
             then 1 
        end
      end as mapping , code
```

Comment: Thank for correcting my code and simplifying Gordon solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `like`.  SQL Server supports character ranges using square braces, so the first three patterns are:

```
where code like '[A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' or
      code like '[A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' or
      code like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' or
      . . .
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This solution helps but I have marked Simon solution as the best answer because of code reuse .